# Convert string object created from a class to list

Tags: python

In the task, I am trying to create an object of a deck of cards. The output is something like ['A of Hearts', 'A of Diamonds', 'A of Clubs', ...] and what I want is to convert the output to a list and get the length of the list.

After I created an instance from the class, I tried to get the type of the output, and it returns `<class '__main__.Card'>`.

I tried to convert the output, which should be a string, into a list by:

1. Split the output string
2. directly use list() function

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.suit = ["Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"]
        self.value = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
        self.cards = [] 

        for x in self.value:
            y = x + " of"
            for z in self.suit :
                aa = y + " " + z
                self.cards.append(aa)

    def __repr__(self): 
        return str(self.cards) 

cards1 = Card()
```

When I use the first function, it returns error 
'Card' object has no attribute 'split'

When I use the second function, it returns error 'Card' object is not iterable

In this case what should I do?
Many thanks

Comment: What are the first and second functions?

Comment: you should provide a minimal reproducible example for us to understand your issue

Comment: The list of the cards is `cards1.cards`.  If you wanted the string version, you'd have to call `repr(cards1)` - you could call `.split()` on that, but that would be silly when you have the data in a list already.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  You refer to "the output", but your **__init__** returns a formed deck -- already a list -- as an object; there is no "output" as we usually use the term.  You split a string, not a list.  This is also confusing because you've named your deck class "Card", as if it referred to a single card.

Comment: Hi all, actually what I want to do is to set another class (let's say Deck) and to count the number of elements there. 

Since I am still very new to this, so it may be a very silly design ... but thanks you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to just get the output in string form, then use an `f` string or a formatted string:

```
str1 = f"test1: {cards1}"
str2 = "test2: {}".format(cards1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the class is not fine, but it works. You are returning an object, this object should have a method to return the string/list or you have to directly get the list as follow.

```
str1 = ''.join(cards1.cards)
```